# Problems implementing tabs in ActionBarSherlock 4

Tags: android, actionbarsherlock

I really want to get this to work, but I feel like I've been floundering about for hours.  I'm starting up a new app and want to try to follow the UI guidelines as close as possible, which for anything below ice-cream sandwich seems to mean I need to use ActionBarSherlock.  Looking at the example [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/actionbar.html) it looks like it should be straightforward.

I try to implement it and it doesn't work because FragmentActivity does not have a getSupportActionBar() method.

Taking a look at the [demo app](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ActionBarSherlock/tree/4.0-wip/samples/demos/src/com/actionbarsherlock/sample/demos) and it seems they don't use FragmentActivity, they use SherlockActivity.  Well, SherlockActivity does have a getSupportActionBar() method, so that's promising.  Continuing on with the example for a while...

Okay, now it seems the com.actionbarsherlock.app.ActionBar.TabListener doesn't pass FragmentTransaction to its events?  Not only that, but the SherlockActivity doesn't have a getSupportFragmentManager() method...

Am I (hopefully) just doing something completely wrong?  How do I keep encountering all these issues that no one else is?  I feel like I'm going nuts here. The only potentially related issue I've found is [here](http://groups.google.com/group/actionbarsherlock/browse_thread/thread/2469f6b37fdf68e4) and it's not very useful.

Comment: Are you using the support library to support fragments? Or are you targeting Honeycomb and above?

Comment: The support library.  I believe the plan is API 7 and above.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

You need to extend from SherlockFragmentActivity instead of only SherlockActivity or SherlockFragment. This way you will get access to ABS and the Fragment Support.

Comment: In my opinion, this is the right answer. At least this worked for me. No need to use any additional library like SimonVT proposes!

Answer (score 1):

I ran into a similar problem trying to get a map view and fragments to work with actionbarsherlock. See [my post](http://groups.google.com/group/actionbarsherlock/browse_thread/thread/87fa0b4d85daa9ff) on the mailing list.

The solution I came up with was to get the sources for the compatibility library and modify the `FragmentActivity` to extend a `SherlockActivity` instead of a standard android Activity.

Then you'll need to compile the sources for the support library along with your app(in some fashion).

In my case I went an additional step to modify the SherlockActivity to extend MapActivity, but since you didn't mention maps, you wouldn't need to do that.

There may be other solutions, but this at least got things to work for me.

I would recommend the [mailing list](http://groups.google.com/group/actionbarsherlock) as this project seems to be changing frequently.

Comment: This actually will not completely work because the menu implementation in `FragmentActivity` will overwrite what is in `SherlockActivity`. There is a purpose built .jar of the support lib with a proper ABS implementation for precisely this situation, however.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use extend from com.actionbarsherlock.app.SherlockFragmentActivity and take a look at https://github.com/inazaruk/examples/tree/master/MapFragmentExample to see how to use a Map with Fragments.